# Regular expression to match string containing character

Tags: regex

I have a file that contains several strings bounded by single quotations (`'`). These strings can contain whitespace and sometimes occur over multiple lines; however, no string contains a quotation (`'`) mark. I'd like to create a regex that finds strings containing the character `"$"`. The regex I had in mind: `'[^']*\$[^']*` can't search over multiple lines. How can I get it to do so?

Comment: What language/tool are you using the regex for?

Comment: In Perl, the `m` modifier. In languages that promise Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, there should be some way to pass a flag option to the regex compile step.

Comment: @jdlugosz: The `m` modifier affects behavior of `^` and `$` and has nothing to do with whether the regex process 1 line at a time or the whole file at once. That behavior is determined by the code to read input (read one line at a time, or read all lines into a single big string)

Comment: Did I mean `s`? It's been a while .  Point is to make newline match a dot or exclusive range., like any normal char would.

Comment: @jdlugosz Since the OP does not use the dot in the expression, the `s` modifier won't make a difference.

Comment: "Anything that's not a single quote" is an exclusive range.  We don't want the kliene star to halt at the newline as being the end of string.  I supposed that he had the content to be searched in a string, but wasn't working when the string contained \n chars.

Comment: Pretty please, read the [tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and in particular the importance of tagging your regex questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex *can* search over multiple lines. If it doesn't there is a mistake in your code *outside* of it. (hint: `[^']` does include newlines).

How about this expression (it prevents useless backtracking):

```
'([^'$]*\$[^']*)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling us which language you are using, so we are left to speculate.  There are two issues here, really:

- Many regex engines only process one line at a time by default
- Some regex engines cannot process more than one line at a time

If you are in the former group, we can help you.  But the problem isn't with the regex, so much as it's with how you are applying it.  (But I added the missing closing single quote to your regex, below, and the negation to prevent backtracking as suggested in Tomalak's answer.)

In Python 2.x:

```
# doesn't work
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # This is broken because it examines a single line of input
        print "match" if re.search(r"'[^'$]*\$[^']*'", line)
# works
s = ''
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s += line
# We have collected all the input lines.  Now examine them.
print "match" if re.search(r"'[^'$]*\$[^']*'", s)
```

(That is **not** the idiomatic, efficient, correct way to read in an entire file in Python.  I'm using clumsy code to make the difference obvious.)

Now, more idiomatically, what you want could be

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while (m/\x27[^\x27$]*\$[^\x27]*\x27/g) { print "$&\n" }' file
```

(the `\x27` is a convenience so I can put the whole script in single quotes for the shell, and not strictly necessary if you write your Perl program in a file), or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
with open('file', 'r') as f:
  for match in re.match(r"'[^'$]*\$[^']*'", f.read()):
    print match
```

Similar logic can be applied in basically any scripting language with a regex engine, including `sed`.  If you are using `grep` or some other simple, low-level regex tool, there isn't really anything you can do to make it examine more than one line at a time (but some clever workarounds are possible, or you could simply switch to a different tool -- `pcregrep` comes to mind as a common replacement for `grep`).

If you have really large input files, reading it all into memory at once may not be a good idea; perhaps you can devise a way to read only as much as necessary to perform a single match at a time.  But that already goes beyond this simple answer.